# HighChart: Donut Pie with URL

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a pie chart in Highcharts. Clicking on a slice of the pie should load the URL associated with that data series. For example, if there is a 25% slice with a url to `yahoo.com` and a 35% slice to `google.com`, then clicking on the 35% slice should take the user to `google.com`.

This is what I added in the series:

```
// ...
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            location.href = e.point.url;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
// ...

data = [{
      y: 55.11,
      color: colors[0],
      url: 'www.google.com', 
      drilldown: {
         name: 'MSIE versions',
         categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
         data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
         url: 'www.google.com',
         color: colors[0]
      }
}, { .......many more dataset ...
```

I have one example JS fiddle as above, but it [is not working](http://jsfiddle.net/sxskW/7/).

In the same example somebody suggested to add `url` in the series, but that would make all the slices to point to the same URL.

This example is similar [but also does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/sxskW/6/).

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Comment: Just fixed the link. Appreciate.

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please.

Comment: I don`t think thats a rule. I thought JFiddle contains code and that should satisfy the requirement??

Comment: No, no it is not... those links die. And then this question becomes useless. **Please**  post some code.

Comment: Oh!! Got it. Will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging the broken examples, the problem is that the `url` is not included in the data passed in to the chart:

```
// add browser data
browserData.push({
    name: categories[i],
    y: data[i].y,
    color: data[i].color,

    // missing this line!
    url: data[i].url
 });
```

Once that is done, it is as easy as the [docs describe](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events.click):

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            location.href = this.options.url;
        }
    }
}
```